# Вывести повторяющиеся элементы на нечетных индексах (Java)

Tags: java, массивы

Есть рандомный массив длиной 20, нужно вывести все элементы, которые встречаются больше одного раза и индексы которых нечётные. Собственно, это вроде как получилось.

Теперь нужно сделать так, чтобы эти повторяющиеся элементы выводились только 1 раз, при этом указывалось, на каких индексах они стоят. (То есть если у нас три раза повторяются пятерки на 1, 3, 5 индексах, нужно чтобы вывел только одну пятерку, и рядом все ее нечетные индексы.)

Можно работать только с циклами и массивами, никаких коллекций и т.д.

Хэлп, плиз, что нужно добавить в код?

```java
public class OneSix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] elements = new int[20];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 20) - 10);
    }

    printArray(elements);
    firstAlgorithm(elements);
  }
  private static void firstAlgorithm(int[] data) {
    int[] elements = new int[data.length];

    System.arraycopy(data, 0, elements, 0, data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < elements.length - i; j++) {
        if (elements[i] == elements[i + j] && i % 2 != 0) {
          int[] indexes = new int[data.length];

          indexes[i] = i;
          System.out.print(elements[i] + "\t");
          System.out.println("Индекс дублирующегося элемента: " + indexes[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  private static void printArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Массив случайных чисел `0-9`:

```java
int[] arr = IntStream.range(0, 20)
        .map(i -> (int) (Math.random() * 10))
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
//[9, 3, 7, 9, 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 9, 4, 1, 6, 8, 0, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5]
```

Массив элементов с нечетными индексами:

```java
int[] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> i % 2 != 0)
        .map(i -> arr[i])
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
// [3, 9, 0, 4, 9, 1, 8, 5, 6, 5]
```

Массив элементов, встречающихся больше одного раза:

```java
int[] arr3 = IntStream.range(0, arr2.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> arr2[i], Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
// [5, 9]
```